# HttpUrlConnection sometimes works too slow

Tags: java, http, proxy, httpurlconnection

I download files from URL's with my code.It works very well to download files.But sometimes I have problem about it.Here is the code.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",myproxy);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","80");

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
con.setReadTimeout(10000);

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

InputStream is =    con.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Inputstream done");

FileOutputStream fos = fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\tryfile\\file1.csv");

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];              //declare 4KB buffer
    int len;

    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {

        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

  fos.close();
  is.close();
```

Usually that code downloads the files in 1 or 2 seconds and works perfect.But sometimes it takes 3-4 minutes to download same file.

For example I sent 4 HTTP Request one by one.Usually it doesn't have problem.It sent 4 http request and download 4 file from  4 different URL's perfectly.

But sometimes the first request waits 3 or 4 minutes to work.And after waiting 3 or 4 minutes it take response from url and download file perfectly and after all of that second,third and fourth requests work perfect and download files in 2 seconds.(So the only problem is why sometimes it waits 3 or 4 minutes in first requests)

It only happens sometimes.And I don't know why.And when it happens connect and readtimeouts doesn't work.It waits 3 or 4 minutes without take timeout exception.

I debug the code and I think when the code starts to wait it happens on that line.

- int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

Why it happens?Any idea?
Maybe the proxy or anything else.I really want to know why it happens.
And it is very intresting that the problem only happens sometimes and only happens in first request.

Comment: If it's about just first request, maybe dns lookup issue(not sure), try the same ith target ip to make sure

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.Please add some more detail.

Comment: let say url is `abcd.com`, so system first must find out what ip is mapped to this domain, this means dns-lookup. Since clients cache the first lookup, so if the first request if time-consuming, it would be because of dns-lookup.

Comment: So,can I do anyhing from the code or what can I do for this problem?

Comment: not any logical and reliable method out there, first try to change your dns server to google public dns server(8.8.8.8), usually this helps. another bad way is calling the domain by its ip directly rather than domain name which is not recommended, but since its ip it will skip dns look-up.

Comment: So,I will try calling domain by ip directly.But I wonder what is the risk of this way?Why its not recommended?